# Can I use google Custom Search JSON API free version without ad?

Tags: google-custom-search

I like to know, can I use google Custom Search JSON API without ad?

Also, I can pay for additional search queries here.
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing

Comment: Did you find an answer to your query? I am wondering the same.

Comment: no. it is not documented anywhere. waiting for someone answer.